# Calculating percentile over multiple large files without holding them all in memory (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, bigdata, percentile

I'm trying to calculate the 99th percentile of a certain value in a climate dataset. I have hourly observations spread across a lat-lon grid of 361 x 576 points for 43 years (1980-2022).

Is there a way to iteratively calculate the 99th percentile by loading in each year one by one and discarding some amount of the previous data to keep the memory needed limited? I've done some reading on algorithms but haven't found anything yet that would suit my needs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thought is a map-reduce type algorithm to get a decent approximation. Use it compute min and max of the entire set from which to define value buckets. A distributed sort/count can compute bucket sizes. When you're done, final bucket sizes should give a decent approximate histogram. Second thought is: why does this take "~5 min per point"? It doesn't seem _that_ big a dataset, though perhaps a more database-like tool (perhaps sqlite, even) will work better than reading files locally into Python.

Comment: What data type are the "observations"?

Comment: @Kache The time is due to reading in & subsetting each yearly file by the lat/lon values, not the actual percentile calculation. I'll look into map-reduce algorithms, thanks.

Comment: @KellyBundy the data are floats.

Comment: @KellyBundy They are 3D arrays: each yearly file is 8760 x 361 x 576.

Comment: I think it would be good to state that in the question. How much time would be acceptable? Does your drive have enough free space for a copy of the data?

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks, I added the size to the original question. Ideally this should not take more than a couple days. I would be ok with a good approximation as well. I've experimented with taking yearly 99th percentiles & averaging them but that's not ideal.

Comment: @Stef Thank you, that looks promising. I don't have any experience with that module though - how exactly would I only keep 1%?

Comment: @fivebyfive Decide in advance how many items you want to keep (I don't know how many items you have, but let's say you have 100000 items; then you decide to keep 1% of that, which is 1000 items). Build a heap with the first 1000 items using `heapq.heapify`. Then loop over the remaining 99000 items: for every item, use `heapq.heappushpop` to add the new item to the heap and discard the smallest item from the heap.

Comment: @Stef Thank you!! Does heapify maintain the dimensions of the data (e.g. I have 361 x 576 lat lon points, I want to be sure that I can calculate individual percentiles for each point this way)

Comment: @fivebyfive No, in that case I'm afraid you'd have to use 361x576 heapqs, I guess. Note this is just an idea. I don't know enough about your problem to know whether it's a good idea or not.

Comment: Heaps are a relatively basic data structure. You can build a `361 x 576 x (K+1)` array where K is the number of maximum item to find. Inserting a new value in the heap is basically copying a slice of size `361 x 576` and checking the parent slice which is SIMD friendly so it can be very fast. The removal of the min is quite the opposite operation (top down) but with `O(log n)` try. This last operation is quite expensive, but this should be very-fast overall. The removal of the min can be optimized and parallelized (by splitting slices in N parts) using Numba. This could even be done on a GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Stef's observation that we only need to keep track of the top 1%, but I do that with NumPy arrays and partitioning:

```py
import numpy as np

# Simulated files (3x5 grid instead of 361x576)
def files():
    np.random.seed(123)
    for year in range(43):
        yield np.random.random((8760, 3, 5))

# Just for testing; Compute expectation with np.percentile
def reference(files):
    whole = np.vstack(files)
    return np.percentile(whole, 99, 0, method='closest_observation')

# The actual solution
def solution(files):

    # Preparation for getting top 1% = top k
    k = round(43 * 8760 / 100)
    def top_k(a):
        return np.partition(a, ~k, 0)[~k:]

    # Compute the result
    result = top_k(next(files))
    for other in files:
        other = top_k(other)
        both = np.vstack((result, other))
        result = top_k(both)
    return result[0]

expect = reference(files())
result = solution(files())

print('expect:')
print(expect)

print('\nresult:')
print(result)

print('\ndifference:')
print(result - expect)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVNLbtswEF10p1MMEBSmCiW1q9hJXGTVXVcF2l0aBIw0sglJJEEOE3uTI_QC3WTTHKqnKT-SbVUbafjezLw3I_5-03vaKvn6-sdRc379990v0WtlCKTr9R64Bamz7Ay-i951nLCGRnRogZW7JWyMqEFIS8hrUA2Uq8VuebXKsxqbxGP5OgP_SH1huKxVf2ERa7b4VObxvFEG9siNrwKesEF2WQ4p4dkL7OqT5PRi7PpqNS-gLGCZ50HdV2cp1iK0JOTmM3xRvXaEgDuNFXESSsKzoG0optFUKMnri0INNmhQVsii5KH981Z1CLeB_2SJV-2ARtAgOSOntVjMKODmpgAvrkc_1_p2VnXKelEP6tGieYpCZlHzjy0Cr8jxDqzqXACinDE4qIkdz-CbQc1NchKsbpCCVSClYfHeKw0fbSS3PjLKydpPEz5AmBZ8hMV8ntSHLp780DJ-MusTT9yQiBJ4AS-tt5PfvbTr-1HJOFvyDgxa19EwlPCZhPjaEnc0eDjuWvmcuOwIHJun8zE1RvkBfPTxZBMstSpSWp6feJhICImThSX8bu6tpB8jDGq6fubLHcpMdxGgTBshic1S-tqvMh2k-Ij_lKnIkZHiU0YtmqH1_yw4H37cPF3L4XaOt_Qf)):

```
expect:
[[0.98989099 0.98997275 0.99009619 0.98969514 0.99034828]
 [0.9898165  0.99010689 0.98995486 0.99006558 0.98968308]
 [0.98996179 0.98979965 0.9896849  0.98996829 0.99012452]]

result:
[[0.98989099 0.98997275 0.99009619 0.98969514 0.99034828]
 [0.9898165  0.99010689 0.98995486 0.99006558 0.98968308]
 [0.98996179 0.98979965 0.9896849  0.98996829 0.99012452]]

difference:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

With simulated 36x58 grid, the "Compute the result" part took less than 30 seconds, on the ATO site. So for your real data on your own computer, it should take less than an hour.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked excellently. I had been trying something similar but was unaware of the np.partition function, that makes it so concise! One quick question if you don't mind - why did you add 1 to the rounded k value?

Comment: @fivebyfive Honestly I added the 1 because that made the result match the `np.percentile` result :-). I was too lazy to read/think about what it should be exactly, it was trial&error. Note that in `np.percentile`, I used `method='closest_observation'`, and that it offers multiple other methods. I didn't know which one you want (or what future visitors want), so you might want to slightly adjust anyway. By now I also removed that 1, now using `~` instead of `-` for backwards indexing. So, did you run it already? How long did it take?

Comment: Ah gotcha! Yes I ran it - it took about 1h30 total. Very reasonable, and the results look great (& in line with what I expected from previous methods, always reassuring!). Thank you so much!

Comment: @fivebyfive Ok, slower than I estimated, but not much. Maybe if you don't have much memory, it could be further improved by letting go of data as soon as it's not needed anymore. That is, `del result, other` before the `result = top_k(both)`, and `del both` afterwards.